# SSIS script component as source Null value

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, adomd.net, script-component

I have package in SSIS that loads data using adomd.Net from essbase cube. With 2 columns package works fine, but when I add 3. column package fails.

Error message says:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Third column in the first row contains *null* and some values in other rows.

Problem looks in *null* value in the 3. column. 
I tried this if statement but I get empty column instead of values.

```
AdomdDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        using (AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(query, conn))
            {
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    Output0Buffer.AddRow();

                    Output0Buffer.Column = (reader.GetString(0));
                    Output0Buffer.Column1 = (reader.GetString(1));

                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
                    {
                        Output0Buffer.Column2 = "test";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Output0Buffer.Column2 = (reader.GetString(2));
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("fin");
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);

        throw;
    }
```

Comment: please add breakpoints and debug the code to identify the row that throws the exception, then you will get better help

Comment: Right now, the code is only populating a value in the column if it is null `!reader.IsDBNull(2)` -- I think remove the exclamation point and see if that works

Comment: Yes, exclamation was the problem, now solved.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz just write it as an answer :)

Comment: @Hadi - sure thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit of the code is working the opposite way as intended:

```
 if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
  {
      Output0Buffer.Column2 = "test";
  }
  else
  {
      Output0Buffer.Column2 = (reader.GetString(2));
  }
```

`!reader.IsDBNull(2)` means where the value is not null.  Removing the exclamation point will fix the problem